# Finding the alpha parameters of a Dirichlet knowing means and variances

Tags: probability, statistics, systems-of-equations

I have a set of data that I would like to simulate via a Dirichlet distribution, because I need that the sum is 1.
I know that:

$$\Large E(x)=0.5151, Var(x)=0.086^2
E(y)=0.439, Var(y)=0.053^2
E(z)=0.045, Var(z)=0.014^2$$

I am trying to find the vector (a1,a2,a3) in the way that, if I sample in Dir(a1,a2,a3) then my sample set will have the characteristics previously mentionned.

Knowing the expenctancy and variance of the Dirichlet distribution
[variance and expectancy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I99It.png)
, I am building an equation system:
\begin{cases}\LARGE 0.5151=\frac{a1}{(a1+a2+a3)} \\\LARGE 0.439=\frac{a2}{(a1+a2+a3)} \\\LARGE 0.045=\frac{a3}{(a1+a2+a3)}\\\LARGE0.086*0.086=\frac{a1*(a2+a3)}{((a1+a2+a3)*(a1+a2+a3)*(a1+a2+a3+1))}\\\LARGE0.053*0.053=\frac{a2*(a1+a3)}{((a1+a2+a3)*(a1+a2+a3)*(a1+a2+a3+1))}\\\LARGE 0.014*0.014=\frac{a3*(a1+a2)}{((a1+a2+a3)*(a1+a2+a3)*(a1+a2+a3+1))}
\end{cases}

However, this system has 6 equations and 3 unknowns.
Do you have any idea of how to solve it?
Also, am I doing it correctly if I want to have a Dirichlet distribution to model my process?

Comment: I found in the literature that this kind of problem is linked with compositional data analysis

Comment: There won't exist fitting Dirichlet distribution unless you're really lucky. What kind of dataset is this?

Comment: They represent mass fraction compositions of a compound made of 3 materials (mean and associated std deviation). My goal is to sample possible compounds knowing these values. That is why I choose a Dirichlet as the sum should be 100%

Comment: So I would try how well you can do with Dirichlet. Set $a_1 = 0.5151\lambda, a_2 = 0.439\lambda, a_3 = 0.045\lambda$ And optimize w.r.t $\lambda$. As your distribution is quite tight (low variances) I expect it'll yield quite good result. If not I would fit Gamma distributions to x, y and z components and then use $X/(X+Y+Z)$ and so on for compound distribution.

Comment: Another approach would be to use use Gaussian distribution on the hyperplane and ignore negative values of mass fractions, which should appear extremely rarely.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is not so bad. Using $$a1=16.88, a2=14.39, a3=1.51$$ I can reproduce the mean, but not exactly the std that become $$std(x)=0.086, std(y)= 0.086=/=0.053, std(z)=0.035 =/=0.014$$. Is it possible to improve it? With Gaussian distributions, I tried but I never get that sum of materials = 100 %. I tried to renormalize but it changes the std deviation which become not correct. Anyway, it is already a good start but, do you have an idea of a way to improve it?

Comment: With the second method (beta for each variable then renormalization), the std of the generated set is changed and does not correspond.

Comment: Did you try Gaussian on the hyperplane, i.e. $(U, V)\sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$ and $(X, Y, Z) = (U, V, 1-U-V)$? This has 5 parameters so should yield better fit

Comment: Unfortunately I tried and it does not work becayse the constraint 1-U-V adds information in the distribution. Hence the std deviation is reduced for the last parameter